# Java method said to return object of Class but returns object of SubClass

Tags: java, casting, return-type

There is [a method](https://github.com/dcm4che/dcm4che/blob/master/dcm4che-net/src/main/java/org/dcm4che3/net/Association.java#L961):

```
public DimseRSP cfind(String asuid, String cuid, int priority,
        Attributes data, String tsuid, int autoCancel) throws IOException,
        InterruptedException {
    FutureDimseRSP rsp = new FutureDimseRSP(nextMessageID());
    rsp.setAutoCancel(autoCancel);
    cfind(asuid, cuid, priority, data, tsuid, rsp);
    return rsp;
}
```

that I'm calling in my application like

```
DimseRSP rsp = association.cfind(...
```

then I can use

```
rsp.someMethodOfTheDimseRSPClass()
```

which works, but I'd like to call

```
rsp.someMethodOfTheFutureDimseRSPClass()
```

instead, which should be possible as `rsp` is an instance of `FutureDimseRSP` that is actually returned from the `cfind()`, but of course my IDE gives me an error because it thinks that `rsp` is only a `DimseRSP`.

What should I do? Can I cast `DimseRSP` to a `FutureDimseRSP` somehow so it would work?

Comment: "Can I cast DimseRSP to a FutureDimseRSP" Yes, that sounds reasonable, assuming that it always will return one... so have you tried it?

Comment: If the method will always return a `FutureDimseRSP`, why isn't its return value that? Casting is often a sign of lacking design.

Comment: @Kayaman I don't know, I also find it strange and that's why I'm unsure what to do. Jon Skeet I tryed casting it and it works. I should have formulate my question more like "what is the preferred thing to do in a situation like that?" Just cast it and that's it?

Comment: @Kayaman Maybe the API wants to allow that method to be overridable and in those cases allow returning other types that inherit from DimseRSP.

Comment: @MaxVollmer then the overriding method should use the subclass as return type, since return types are covariant. Sill not an excuse for bad design.

Comment: @Kayaman Uhm, I think you missed my point. If the base method already returns the subclass, then the overriding method obviously cannot return the superclass or another subclass of the superclass.

Comment: @MaxVollmer no, the overriding method returns the subclass. The baseclass returns the superclass. If the code were of a subclass, its return type would be the subclass. Assuming proper design, which I'm not at all convinced is present in this codebase...and by looking at the linked codebase we can see that it's not a subclass at all. It's some sort of god class with a huge amount of methods.

Comment: @Kayaman What do you mean, "no"? The method signature says the return type is DimseRSP. That's the superclass. The method returns FutureDimseRSP. That's a subclass. You wondered why the return type isn't FutureDimseRSP (again, a subclass). I speculated that the API wants to allow overriding methods to return subclasses of DimseRSP (again, the superclass). If the return type was changed to FutureDimseRSP, then overriding methods could only return FutureDimseRSP or subclasses of FutureDimseRSP, but not other subclasses of DimseRSP.

Comment: @MaxVollmer yes of course if you think of it that way (although then you should make an abstract superclass/interface with the specified method and the superclass return type). In any case if you look at the codebase the class has no subclasses (and doesn't look like its made to be subclassable) and seems to be just a regular case of poor design.

Comment: I don't think we have *nearly* enough context to know if it's bad design or not. Sometimes declaring a general return type is *good* design to allow for later flexibility... but it would suggest that the casting is problematic. Sometimes it's better to return the more precise type to start with. I don't think we're in a position to judge at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're scared that `rsp` might not always be an **instance of** `FutureDimseRSP`, use `instanceof`:

```
if (rsp instanceof FutureDimseRSP) {
    ((FutureDimseRSP)rsp).someMethodOfTheFutureDimseRSPClass();
}
else {
    // handle this...
}
```

Comment: It's not good design to ignore things when you get classes that you don't expect. Or having to use `instanceof` because you don't know what classes you're dealing with.

Comment: @Kayaman Generally yes, but if you have an API you have no control over, and it acts in certain undesirable ways, you have to deal with it. The problem is that you cannot know if the method body of the API as it is now will stay the same in future updates. It's public signature promises a DimseRSP, not a FutureDimseRSP. If you want to work with the FutureDimseRSP, you must cast. If you want to make sure your code doesn't break unexpectedly if the inner workings of the API change, you must check first. You are right about the ignore part, will edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is technically correct, you *can* check the type, to make a **downcast** if possible.

But thing is: doing so is most often the *wrong* approach. Because the whole point of "the signature says it returns the super class" is that you do **not** need to make downcasts.

In other words: the simple solution is to check/cast. The better solution is to step back to get the whole picture and to then decide if there is a way to avoid doing that check/cast. For example by moving that method into the super class. Or by defining an interface that defines that method, so that your method returns that interface. Or, or, or - many options.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to cast, then you can always add the abstract function or a normal function of "someMethodOfTheFutureDimseRSPClass" in DimseRSP class and by inheritance ,the function "someMethodOfTheFutureDimseRSPClass" which is a part of FutureDimseRSP class will be called.

Comment: That would require control over the `DimseRSP` class, and if OP had that, OP could as easily change the return type of the `cfind` method.